# Validate CCYYMMDD date using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

What is the best way to validate a date, that it is actually a date if the input format is in CCYYMMDD as a string (i.e. "20101210")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an exception thrown if the date is not valid, then do this:

```
Dim date As Datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(theDateString, "yyyyMMdd", _
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you do not want an exception thrown if the data is not valid, then do this:

```
Dim myDate As Date    
If Date.TryParseExact(theDateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, _
    DateTimeStyles.None, myDate) Then
    ' Conversion succeeded
Else
    ' Conversion failed
End If
```

Comment: You can't call your variable that without surrounding it with square brackets. `Date` is a reserved keyword, and VB is case insensitive.

Comment: How do I know if the date is invalid in Option 2?

Comment: @NickLaMarca - I have edited the answer to show that `TryParseExact` returns a `Boolean`, which you can conditionally perform logic, based upon the success or failure of the attempted conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx).  It takes a date format string along with a date string and will return false if the string does not match the format exactly.